# jQuery FullCalendar - Custom Headings

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar, really impressed so far. Is it possible to show the number of events in the heading, for example, in week view the title shows Mon-Fri, if I have 4 events on the Monday, can I customise the heading to say Mon (4 Events) ??

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function :

```
eventAfterAllRender : function( view ) {

            eventsCount = $('.fc-view-'+view.name+' .fc-event').length;

            if(!view.title.match(/\(*.\)/g)){

              view.title += ' ('+eventsCount+' event'+(eventsCount > 1?'s':'')+')'

            }
            else{

               view.title.replace(/\(*.\)/g , ' ('+eventsCount+' event'+(eventsCount > 1?'s':'')+')')

            }
        }
```

see this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m5XTY/

Comment: eventAfterAllRender doesn't appear to work when loading events using AJAX ?

Comment: eventAfterAllRender was added in fullcalendar 1.6 what version do you use? try this jsfiddle it also work fine with eventAfterRender http://jsfiddle.net/m5XTY/1/

Comment: Thanks, have just realised that, have upgraded and will let you know how I get on.

Comment: finaly eventAfterRender don't work forget my previous comment